Should I use "A/an + adj. + Name" or "The + adj. + Name"?
As a native English speaker, I find myself perplexed by this situation. Here are some examples of what I mean.
1.1 The worried Link went to see Impa.
1.2 A worried Link went to see Impa.
2.1 The angry Boober threw his pen against the table.
2.2 An angry Boober threw his pen against the table.
3.1 Sir Hiss slithered as fast as he could from the stark raving mad Prince John.
3.2 Sir Hiss slithered as fast as he could from a stark raving mad Prince John.
4.1 I wouldn't want to face the furious Negan.
4.2 I wouldn't want to face a furious Negan.
I believe that it is possible to rewrite the phrase when it is the subject as "Link, worried, …" and "Boober, angry, …." When the phrase is the predicate, I could probably rewrite it as "…Prince John, who had gone stark raving mad," and "…Negan when he's furious."
I hope that someone can help me get to the bottom of this.

All your examples are "marked, literary", and best avoided unless you aspire to be a published writer. In "normal" English, Link, who was worried, went to see Impa,  Boober angrily threw his pen against the table,  Sir Hiss slithered as fast as he could from Prince John, who was stark raving mad, I wouldn't want to face Negan when he is furious. Note that using the indefinite article (a, an) with a proper noun (someone's name, for example) is extremely "poetic", because literally it implies that "worried Link" really is a different person to "normal" Link.

4.1 implies that Negan is generally furious, and you never want to face him. 4.2 means that he's not always furious, you just want to avoid facing him when he is.

@Barmar nails it. Worth an Answer posting.

@YosefBaskin This seems like something that would have been answered before, so there should be a duplicate, but I'm not finding one.

It's kind of similar to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111788/use-of-articles-with-personal-names-modified-by-adjectives
